# Need help applying script to just one sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a simple script to apply a duration format to a form submission. It works great except that it is being applied to every sheet in the workbook instead of the one I am specifying in the script. Any and all help  is appreciated.

```
 // Set Form input to duration
    
 function Durationformat(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var names = ss.getSheetByName('Capt Log Responses 1');
 ss.getRange('P2:P').setNumberFormat('[hh]:mm:ss');


}
```

Not sure where to go from here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to change the format of Capt Log Responses 1!P2:P, you can try this:

```
 function durationFormat(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var names = ss.getSheetByName('Capt Log Responses 1');
 names.getRange('P2:P').setNumberFormat('[hh]:mm:ss');    
}
```

Changed `ss` to `names` in the final line of code to only apply change to "Capt Log Resonses 1".

Comment: Ok, So that seems to work. I am at a loss as to the difference. I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: `Names` calls just the sheet.  `ss` calls the whole spreadsheet.

Comment: If that works for you, please mark it as accepted.  That helps all of us looking for posts with answers that have not been accepted know when something has been resolved.  Thank you.

Comment: Marked. Again thanks for the quick response!